# ITelephony .java not generating properly

Tags: android, eclipse

I followed the right procedure to generate the ITelephony.java class in my eclipse project.

But it does not seem to generate properly since I've got frequencea lot red warning in the file. I'm running under ubuntu 12.04 64 bits. Strange thing though, it does work on my work PC running under windows . Thing is I really need to get work on my laptop to be able to work from home.

I'm using Juno version of eclipse on both devices.

What could cause this problem?

Any answer/idea would be great because I really don't know how to fix it.

Edit 1: Sorry forgot to specify the errors I get. All of the same type, for example with "@Override public android.os.IBinder asBinder()
{
return this;
}"

I get : "The method asBinder() of type ITelephony.Stub must Override a superclass method" and "implements androidod.IIterface.asBinder".

Here is the fully generated file :

```
/*
 * This file is auto-generated.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 * Original file: /home/lenore/workspace/Launcher/src/com/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony.aidl
 */
package com.android.internal.telephony;
public interface ITelephony extends android.os.IInterface
{
/** Local-side IPC implementation stub class. */
public static abstract class Stub extends android.os.Binder implements com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony
{
private static final java.lang.String DESCRIPTOR = "com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony";
/** Construct the stub at attach it to the interface. */
public Stub()
{
this.attachInterface(this, DESCRIPTOR);
}
/**
 * Cast an IBinder object into an com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony interface,
 * generating a proxy if needed.
 */
public static com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony asInterface(android.os.IBinder obj)
{
if ((obj==null)) {
return null;
}
android.os.IInterface iin = obj.queryLocalInterface(DESCRIPTOR);
if (((iin!=null)&&(iin instanceof com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony))) {
return ((com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony)iin);
}
return new com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony.Stub.Proxy(obj);
}
@Override public android.os.IBinder asBinder()
{
return this;
}
@Override public boolean onTransact(int code, android.os.Parcel data, android.os.Parcel reply, int flags) throws android.os.RemoteException
{
switch (code)
{
case INTERFACE_TRANSACTION:
{
reply.writeString(DESCRIPTOR);
return true;
}
case TRANSACTION_endCall:
{
data.enforceInterface(DESCRIPTOR);
boolean _result = this.endCall();
reply.writeNoException();
reply.writeInt(((_result)?(1):(0)));
return true;
}
case TRANSACTION_dial:
{
data.enforceInterface(DESCRIPTOR);
java.lang.String _arg0;
_arg0 = data.readString();
this.dial(_arg0);
reply.writeNoException();
return true;
}
case TRANSACTION_answerRingingCall:
{
data.enforceInterface(DESCRIPTOR);
this.answerRingingCall();
reply.writeNoException();
return true;
}
}
return super.onTransact(code, data, reply, flags);
}
private static class Proxy implements com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony
{
private android.os.IBinder mRemote;
Proxy(android.os.IBinder remote)
{
mRemote = remote;
}
@Override public android.os.IBinder asBinder()
{
return mRemote;
}
public java.lang.String getInterfaceDescriptor()
{
return DESCRIPTOR;
}
@Override public boolean endCall() throws android.os.RemoteException
{
android.os.Parcel _data = android.os.Parcel.obtain();
android.os.Parcel _reply = android.os.Parcel.obtain();
boolean _result;
try {
_data.writeInterfaceToken(DESCRIPTOR);
mRemote.transact(Stub.TRANSACTION_endCall, _data, _reply, 0);
_reply.readException();
_result = (0!=_reply.readInt());
}
finally {
_reply.recycle();
_data.recycle();
}
return _result;
}
@Override public void dial(java.lang.String number) throws android.os.RemoteException
{
android.os.Parcel _data = android.os.Parcel.obtain();
android.os.Parcel _reply = android.os.Parcel.obtain();
try {
_data.writeInterfaceToken(DESCRIPTOR);
_data.writeString(number);
mRemote.transact(Stub.TRANSACTION_dial, _data, _reply, 0);
_reply.readException();
}
finally {
_reply.recycle();
_data.recycle();
}
}
@Override public void answerRingingCall() throws android.os.RemoteException
{
android.os.Parcel _data = android.os.Parcel.obtain();
android.os.Parcel _reply = android.os.Parcel.obtain();
try {
_data.writeInterfaceToken(DESCRIPTOR);
mRemote.transact(Stub.TRANSACTION_answerRingingCall, _data, _reply, 0);
_reply.readException();
}
finally {
_reply.recycle();
_data.recycle();
}
}
}
static final int TRANSACTION_endCall = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 0);
static final int TRANSACTION_dial = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 1);
static final int TRANSACTION_answerRingingCall = (android.os.IBinder.FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION + 2);
}
public boolean endCall() throws android.os.RemoteException;
public void dial(java.lang.String number) throws android.os.RemoteException;
public void answerRingingCall() throws android.os.RemoteException;
}
```

Comment: what errors are you getting?  Without actually telling us we have no hope of guessing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well I just needed to set the java compiler level to 1.6 instead of 1.5...Facepalm